# Knowing the Value or Result on each variable SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, math

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _spCalc
   (@Num01 decimal(18,0), @Num02 decimal(18,0), @Num03 decimal(18,0))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Var01 float, DECLARE @Var02 float, DECLARE @Var03 float

   SET @Var01 = @Num01 * 1000
   SET @Var02 = @Num02 - ((POWER(6.53 * @Var01, 0.5)) / (POWER(@Num03, 0.5)))
   SET @Var03 = (1 - 3.4680733 * LOG(@Var02) + 1.8779192 * POWER(LOG(@Var02), 2))

   INSERT INTO _myTable(Num01, Num02, Num03, Num04) 
   VALUES (@Num01, @Num02, @Num03, ((@Var02 + @Var03 + @Num01) * 1000))
END
```

My question is, how can I test and know the result of each variable that I declared? I want to compare the result with the calculation on excel format. Just want to make sure, the result is the same.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use "print @var01". repeat for different variable names before or after calculation.this shows up in messages section of results.
or 
we can use " select @var01 as var01,@var02 as var02,@var03 as var03" before your insert statement.this gives you a table like output during execution

you can extend the print or select with other variables as needed.

Comment: The error message is, An invalid floating point operation occurred. On the return value. But if i remove print/select as per your recommend. It works! Other idea?

Comment: Check the values being used, if LOG() gets negative values. try the calculations as separate "select" before assigning to variable.

Comment: "Check the values being used, if LOG() gets negative values" .. Thats the point that i want to check then compare it to excel calc.

Answer (score 1):

I could not add further comments for some reasons.
"try the calculations as separate "select" before assigning to variable"

```
select @Num01 * 1000 as @Var01
select @Num02 - ((POWER(6.53 * @Var01, 0.5)) / (POWER(@Num03, 0.5))) as @Var02
select (1 - 3.4680733 * LOG(@Var02) + 1.8779192 * POWER(LOG(@Var02), 2))
```

substitute the values that u pass to the procedure accordingly